# Display for QEMU

Tags: linux, device-driver, qemu

I am working on linux device drivers and interested to work on display drivers. For start I want to develop a display driver for QEMU emulating arm versatile board. Is there a way to add display to QEMU.

Thanks
-R/\/I-

Answer (score 0):

Firstly QEMU emulator by default supports display, you need not add the display explicitly to qemu, as the name suggests qemu emulator emulates all the hardware supported by the versatile board.

To develop display driver you will have to check the datasheet for versatile-pb, which uses arm primecell colour lcd pl110 .

So, versatile on qemu emulator has LCD emulation.